# Adjacent to the top of the screen CSS

Tags: css, space

How can I remove the space to the div and the top of the screen?
There are a few pixels that can be removed with:

```
margin-top: -8px;
```

But because not all users have the same screen, so probably for anyone on it will show a little differently. How do we fix it?

Comment: try to put a `margin: 0` on your `html` and `body` tags. However, this could also be because of your `html+css`. We need to see those to be able to figure it out

Comment: Are you not using reset.css or normalize css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers set an initial padding on `body`, you can remove it.

```
html, body 
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to browser specific  UA styles,

try resetting the UserAgent with

```
html,body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

for  better undestanding User Agent and resets read [this](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/)